# Access SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION from Wicket

Tags: java, spring-security, wicket

I want to create a Wicket panel as a replacement for the default (and not so beautiful) Spring Security Login page. The form itself is not a big thing, because it's just HTML, but I also want to view Login errors.

I saw many JSP snippets containing `${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION}` for viewing authentication errors, but how can I access this parameter from Wicket?

Answer (score 2):

Accessing this exception from WicketPanel, for example:

```
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel;

public class LogInMenuPanel extends Panel {

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeRender() {
        super.onBeforeRender();

        HttpSession session = ((ServletWebRequest)this.getRequest()).getHttpServletRequest().getSession();
        Throwable exception = (Throwable) session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);

        //do something with exception
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I have never tried it, I think this should be the way:

EDIT: I fixed the bug now

```
    Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
    Object lastException = WebUtils.getSessionAttribute(
        ((ServletWebRequest) request).getHttpServletRequest(),
        WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION
    );
```

See

- [WebAttributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/WebAttributes.html) (Spring, Javadoc)
- [WebUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/WebUtils.html) (Spring, JavaDoc)
- [Constant Field Values:
  AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION) (Spring, JavaDoc)
- [RequestCycle](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/RequestCycle.html) (Wicket, JavaDoc)

Comment: Thanks, but this ends up with a java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebRequest cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Ok, I just found a way to get the HttpServletRequest: HttpServletRequest req = ((ServletWebRequest) getRequest()).getHttpServletRequest();     So, now I have no Exceptions, but the getSessionAttribute method returns null, even if I provide the wrong credentials.

Comment: OK, I fixed my bug now, but I'm amazed it doesn't work because that's pretty much what the spring guys are doing e.g. here: https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-webflow/branches/spring-webflow-2.0-maintenance/spring-webflow-samples/booking-faces/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/login.xhtml